# Android get JNI Library dir

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have a application that has a shared library and a small executable that uses the shared library.

The small executalbe (~2kB) is in assets and I write it to the Cache Directory, which is available by calling `Context.getCacheDir()`. I can start my small executable by putting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/my.app.package/lib` into the environment before starting the process with `ProcessBuilder`.

1. Is there a better way to set the library path?
2. Is there a way to get the library directory without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the library path through ProcessBuilder.environment() seems reasonable to me, and you can get the library directory by calling Context.getApplicationInfo():

```
ApplicationInfo info = getApplicationInfo();
Log.i(TAG, "native library dir = " + info.nativeLibraryDir);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is exactly this directory? is it shared amongst other apps, or is it private for each app? does it get removed when uninstalling the app?